# Avoiding multiple GET requests due to un initialized value of SRC attribute in IMG element

Tags: javascript, html, image, get, src

I have an img element with src attribute

```html
<a><img src="{imgSrc}" alt="Image"></a>
```

The value of imgSrc is generated dynamically when a certain user induced event happens after the page loads.
My problem is, **when the page loads there are a bunch of GET requests being sent to the server since there are many src attributes with imgSrc for the URL and as expected they return 404 errors since the imgSrc is not constructed by the time.**

My question is, is there any way to make sure that the request is not sent to the server when imgSrc variable is not populated with an image URL.

Additional details:

1. This is fully developed web application by some one else and I am fixing defects in this.
2. The developer has designed the application in such a way that almost all src attributes have variable for their URLs and loaded when the page loads, but the URL values are generated only when certain events happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Indeed you may be in great trouble due to poor initial design… You talk about many constraints, but without more details it is hard for people imagining workarounds. It would probably be worth exposing what can be changed. E.g., how the HTML is built, can it be parsed / transformed before being turned into elements, how much are you ready to change the code to have this fixed, etc.

Comment: @ghybs Thank you for your response. It would be difficult to change the code much since it is not a functional defect and my client might not agree to that. This image is nothing but the display picture of the person who comments on a post along with the comment. The element, (i.e.) a DIV element with the person's name,the comment and the image,will not be added to the DOM unless that person comments, but GET request is made anyway, as it is expected.

Comment: Then the dummy image trick might be good enough for your case. It will cease network requests once the image is downloaded, without having to do any other change. And anyway the image will be replaced before it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, browsers will try downloading the resource specified in the `src` attribute of `img` node elements as soon as this attribute is set.

This happens even if the `img` elements are not inserted into the DOM! They just need to be transformed from HTML string into node elements within the current document context (but not necessarily its DOM).

So if you cannot manipulate that HTML string before it is parsed by the browser, there is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent it from trying to fetch the resources.

A dumb workaround would be to provide a dummy image (like a transparent 1px * 1px?) with that exact name, so that browsers are happy and stop requesting it…

If this is an option for you, you could try replacing the entire `img` tag (rather than just its `src` value). But you will need a way to hide the placeholder text so that the user does not see it before you replace it by an actual `img` tag.

Good luck!